# SQLite on iOS: performance and restrictions

Tags: ios, performance, sqlite

Can i use SQLite (or Core Data over SQLite) on iOS, for example on iPad2, in the next cases:

1. Select 10 rows with query that joins 3 tables by indexed columns. Each table contains 5-6 columns and 500 rows. What time approximately does it take?
2. Select from table that contains 5000 rows. What time approximately does it take?

What are the restrictions of using SQLite on iOS (amount of data, number of joins)?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the [SQLite Limits page](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)